# Installing/Configuring SFRA on Mac

Tags: vs-code, commerce-cloud, b2c, mac-os-x, salesfront-reference-architecture

So i am having trouble installing SFRA on Mac
i am currently referring [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/b2c-developer-resources-and-tools/b2c-developer-install-config-sfra?trail_id=develop-for-commerce-cloud&trailmix_creator_id=strailhead) documentation where it says

- Cloned all the repository from git that includes (**storefront-reference-architecture**,  **storefrontdata**,  **sgmf-scripts**).
- Navigated to **storefront-reference-architecture** directory in VS Code.
- Installed **Node 12 Latest version** (as told in documentation).

when i hit `npm install` inside **storefront-reference-architecture** directory in VS code terminal i get **error** as below screenshot

[image]

**here's my folder structure**

[image]

Any idea what am i doing WRONG ?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce recommends Node version 12.21.0,

Can you check in your VsCode your node version before run npm install ?

[image: nvm list]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).